# Extracting a Cosine Function from a Linear Combination of Cosines

Tags: signal-processing

I have a frequency modulated signal which must contain only $ g(t)=B.\cos(\omega(t).t+\phi)$, but it gets the form as below

$$ f(t)=B.\cos(\omega(t).t+\phi)+A_1.\cos(\omega(t-t_1).t+\phi_1)+A_2.\cos(\omega(t-t_2).t+\phi_2)+...$$
where $$A_k<<B$$ $\omega(t)$ values are limited (for instance, it would get values $950<\omega(t)<1050$)

I am going to extract $g(t)$ from $f(t)$. Any suggestion? Note that all sines are in the same frequency bandwidth, therefore filtering does not work.

thank you for your kind replies, in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. :) There is also a specialized community for signal processing. Take a look at http://dsp.stackexchange.com. Maybe you get better answers there. :)

Comment: I supposed there is dedicated to dsp (digital signal processing). I would find more helpful answers from mathematicians. thank you :)

Comment: I don't know about signal processing but it seems to me that you have a numerical data of $f(t)$ which has some noises and these noises are written as $A_k$ terms. Am I right? :) I am a little confused about  what information we have and what we want! Can you add some more details to the question? :)

Comment: Yes, $A_k$s are time-domain shifted version of $g(t)$ which are disturbing.

Comment: So what is known and what is unknown? :) I can't understand that what inputs do you have and what outputs you are looking for! Maybe it is due to my lack of knowledge from SP. :)

Comment: Indeed, I am going to eliminate or reduce effect of $A_k$ in f(t). supposing $A_1$ has maximum value of $A_k$, then one solution would be $$ f(t)-\frac{A_1}{B}.f(t-t_1)$$ since $B>>A1$, so effect of disturbing $A_1$ will be eliminated, but some other minor terms are added to the final result. I wonder if there is other solution to eliminate or reduce effects of disturbing elements with amplitude of $A_k$

Comment: sorry, $$f(t)-\frac{A_1}{B}.f(t-d)$$ where $$d=\frac{\phi_1}{\omega(t+t_1)t_1+\phi}$$

Comment: f(t) is known, g(t) is unknown

Comment: It's not clear if $\phi$ is known, for example. And $w(t)$

Comment: For a simplified form, suppose $\phi=\phi_k=0$.$ \omega(t) $ is unknown.